# Config.cache_classes unitialized constant controller on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I just upgraded my rails project from rails 4.2 to rails 5.1.4. And after the upgrade my maincontroller started crashing. When i call it, it throws an error on the routes file, which states “uninitialized main controller”

After searching for a long time i set on my heroku server the config.cache_classes to false and everything worked all of a sudden. Though i’m unable to reproduce the logic on my local environment.

Anyone that has any idea where to search for a fix or how to fix this? I have been searching for days but without a single hit on what it might be!

Happy to provide any detail that anybody finds it usefully to help out! Just ask!

Ruby version 2.4.2

** EDIT - Added information as requested **

Full error is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant HomeController):

2017-11-26T15:16:55.051341+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051342+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051343+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051343+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051344+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051345+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051346+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051346+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in `controller_class_for'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051347+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:78:in `controller_class'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051348+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `controller'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051348+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `serve'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051349+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051350+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051350+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
2017-11-26T15:16:55.051351+00:00 app[web.1]: vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
```

The controller is based in /myapp/app/HomeController.rb

```
class HomeController < ActionController::API

   def click
    # Execution of method, removed to keep post small
   end
end
```

The routes file in the /myapp/config folder looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 

# root is set to a explainer json  
root to: "home#not_found"

# New Routes
get '/clk', to: 'home#click'

# wildcard for any route not matched
get "*unmatched_route", to: "tracking#not_found"
end
```

Comment: How does your `MainController` look like? Where is its file located? What is the exact error message including the stack trace? How do you reference the `MainController` in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: @spickermann added the details to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, It's related to a change in rails 5 for autoload paths. 
now eager_load_paths should be used in the application.rb instead of autoload_paths

References:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/212ef5278b673aee304519d886d5db86a87b1437
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html